# How to use dockerized database via ssh tunneling in a kubenetes environment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am learning kubernetes (with microk8s) and trying to use postgresql in a k8s cluster (on a local computer).

One of the differences I found with the [official postgres image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) is that it requires setting passwords:

> POSTGRES_PASSWORD
>
> This environment variable is **required** for you to use the PostgreSQL
> image... This environment variable
> sets the superuser password for PostgreSQL...
>
> Note 1: The PostgreSQL image sets up trust authentication locally so
> you may notice a password is not required when connecting from
> localhost (inside the same container). However, a password will be
> required if connecting from a different host/container.

However, I generally do not use passwords with postgres as I mostly use it on localhost. Outside of docker/microk8s environment, I imagine I can SSH tunnel into a postgres server and avoid using passwords. But I don't know much about microk8s or how to do the same with microk8s managed containers. Hence the question here

**Question:**

*How to set up SSH tunneling in dockerized MySQL (or postgres), so that it can be used in a k8s/microk8s cluster?*

**What's tried so far**

I found a git repo [SSH Tunnel as a Kubernetes Service](https://github.com/gfleury/k8s-ssh-tunnel-service). I tried it, but I am obviously missing some steps that the author implicitly assumes. I tried the following in the example:

```
$./ssh-client.py 3306:internal-mysql.example.com:3306 admin@bastion-host.example.com ~/.ssh/id_rsa ssh-tunnel-service-mysql
$ microk8s.kubectl apply -f ssh-tunnel-service-mysql.yaml
service/ssh-tunnel-service-mysql created
configmap/ssh-tunnel-service-mysql created
deployment.apps/ssh-tunnel-service-mysql created
```

But the pods seem to have some errors:

```
$ microk8s.kubectl get pods
NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
ssh-tunnel-service-mysql-7d7f7c6899-tm9fj   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8 (4m10s ago)   20m

$ microk8s.kubectl logs ssh-tunnel-service-mysql-7d7f7c6899-tm9fj
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bastion-host.example.com: Name does not resolve
```

I am very new to microk8s, and has only a fresh setup on Ubuntu 22.04 following the official documentation on [Getting Started](https://microk8s.io/docs/getting-started). I guess I may be missing several important addons and probably steps to build/import MySQL images as implied in the example (which I intend to replace with postgres). Probably only then, the ssh-tunnel service mentioned at the beginning can be used.

*Could anyone help explain the missing steps to make the linked git repo work for a minimal MySQL cluster with the ssh-tunnel service?*

Comment: Every database client library pretty much has username and password as a core configuration option; it seems like it'd be easier to set this up (probably a better practice overall) then to set up complex network paths to not need it.

Answer (score 0):

This setup is not recommended at all.

Assuming you installed the database using `helm`:

```
helm repo add my-repo https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm install my-release my-repo/postgresql
```

a better approach was to:

1. set the password during installation (e.g. if using the helm chart from https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/postgresql you can use following values to override the admin password as well as creating a custom user by setting:

```
global.postgresql.auth.postgresPassword
global.postgresql.auth.username
global.postgresql.auth.password
```

2. use local port forwarding for development

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/my-release-postgresql 5432:5432
```

and following commands to retrieve the password from your cluster and connect via local psql client (make sure to change name of release accordingly):

```
export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default my-release-postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.postgres-password}" | base64 -d)

PGPASSWORD="$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" psql --host 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432
```

---

For production you should make the database available via `Service` and set dedicated user and password and only grant the minimal needed access rights for given clients. (or consider using a hosted service)